# How to put a space in a source code in latex?

Tags: spacing, verbatim, code

I am putting the following code in a latex file  (on overleaf):

```
\begin{verbatim*}
29533000    2   [INFO: ICMP6-IDS] Outgoing ICMP6 packet to ff02::1a
29543040    1   [INFO: ICMP6-IDS] Incoming ICMP6 packet from fe80::202:2:2:2
29543040    3   [INFO: ICMP6-IDS] Incoming ICMP6 packet from fe80::202:2:2:2
\end{verbatim*}
```

The problem is that spaces are converted to ␣ symbol:

```
29533000␣2␣[INFO:␣ICMP6-IDS]␣Outgoing␣ICMP6␣packet␣to␣ff02::1a
29543040␣1␣[INFO:␣ICMP6-IDS]␣Incoming␣ICMP6␣packet␣from␣fe80::202:2:2:2
29543040␣3␣[INFO:␣ICMP6-IDS]␣Incoming␣ICMP6␣packet␣from␣fe80::202:2:2:2
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You could try the linstings package instead: https://ctan.org/pkg/listings .

Comment: Use `verbatim` environment instead of `verbatim*`.

Comment: @hair-splitter post as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `listings` package:

```latex
\usepackage{listings}
```

```latex
\begin{lstlisting}
29533000    2   [INFO: ICMP6-IDS] Outgoing ICMP6 packet to ff02::1a
29543040    1   [INFO: ICMP6-IDS] Incoming ICMP6 packet from fe80::202:2:2:2
29543040    3   [INFO: ICMP6-IDS] Incoming ICMP6 packet from fe80::202:2:2:2
\end{lstlisting}
```

To make the output prettier, you can set a monospace font in the preamble of the document:

```latex
\lstset{
   basicstyle=\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont\ttfamily,
}
```

[image]

Comment: possibly, but a more direct answer would use `verbatim`

Answer (score 2):

The LaTeX verbatim environment prints spaces as normal spaces by default. The starred version of this environment is here if somebody want to emphasize spaces by `␣`. This is documented in each typical LaTeX manual, for example `texdoc lshort` (The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX 2e), section 2.11.5 "Printing verbatim".

You have used starred version (why?) and you are asking, why starred version behaves as starred version.